# How can I generate a very big UIImage (in bytes)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata

For testing purposes I need to generate a very big UIImage (more than 15 MB). I have tried:

```
private func imageWithSize(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    UIColor.orangeColor().setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

But the image is too small (the `NSData` generated by calling `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is less than 15 MB) or the code crashes at `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

Comment: are you sure you need to test things out this way, creating a random garbage UIImage programatically?  UIImage is certainly quite optimized, so creating a massive image of exactly one color is likely to result in a data structure that's simply the width, height, and the orange color with some kind of "this pixel is repeated 100,000 times" pattern indicator.  It would be better to simply *load* a high resolution (over 15MB) PNG image into memory and see if it works well.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann It doesn't seem very optimised, it really looks as if it would generate the image data as if it was a png (it gets to a few MB of the same bytes) ( I also tried painting a few objects, but the size didn't change). The garbage image is only generated while testing.. so... why not?. I don't want to have a 15MB image in my project just for testing purposes, that's why I'm trying to do it programatically

Comment: When you create a UIImage from a file, the image is still not decompress, if you want it to fully uncompress you must display it. The size of an uncompressed image in memory is usually height * width * number_of_channels * number_of_bit_for_channel no matter the file format

Comment: @Andrea I will be using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, the resulting `NSData` will not change if I display the image first.

Comment: @simBob it's not the NSData to change.. but the CGImage created when you display the UIImage. To see that you need to track your application using Allocations. In older version of Xcode the where tagged as "Memory 70", I don't know if the changed something.